# How to validate string as user input (from keyboard) and display "correct answer" using toast?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple game where a question will be asked in a "Plain TextView" and user needs to provide the answer using the keyboard in a "EditText" and press on the check "button" after typing...then a "correct answer" should be displayed on a toast screen if the answer is correct or an "incorrect answer" for wrong answer. I'm a beginner so a detailed answer would be really helpful..thank you.

Here's my Main Activity.Java:

```
package com.example.laxmanaryal.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And here's activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What has 88 keys but cannot open a single door?"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="255dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp" />
```

Comment: We aren't doing your homework for you.  Come up with a much more detailed question about a specific issue and we'll help you.

Comment: @Skizo No, it keeps displaying Fail...maybe it's because the app wants integer?? I'm making the app to accept a string so in the TextView I've written--"What has 88 keys but cannot open a door?" and in the answer part I've written 'if(Answer="piano")' but I'm still getting Fail even when I type "piano"..What's wrong...please help!!   I've got one another query. What operator should I use if I want to have more than one answer. I know in C we can use || for or but it doesn't work in JAVA. For eg: If I want "keyboard" to be answer too will doing: 'if (Answer=="piano" || "keyboard")' work?

Comment: put `if(Answer.equals("piano") || (Answer.equals("keyboard")`

Comment: Yes, I tried, thank you very much, it worked. One little query again...I'm actually not making this app in English. The questions will be in Nepali (similar to indian) and user needs to type answers in the same script. I've tried it in Blue stack and it obviously works fine with different script. But is there anyway that when user taps into the type panel, it automatically displays a Nepali Keyboard instead of English (as English Keyboard is the primary keyboard in every phone)?

Comment: if it worked mark my answer as a correct, since you've a new question you should ask a new question because it's not the same as your currect question, so mark my answer as a correct, create a new question and give me the link and I'll try to help you

Comment: I'd have love to mark your answer as correct...I just didn't know how! I've figured it out and marked it...thank you! But I'm unable to post another question as I've already post a question and it's not been 90 minutes but I need the help as soon as possible. Can you please answer the question above?

Comment: I guess you've to accept your questions... let me check your questions and I'll try to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to declare your `Button` and `EditText` on your `MainActivity`, do as follows.

```
Button button;
EditText edittext;
```

Then inside on your `onCreate()` you have to get the view from your `EditText` and your `Button` so you have to do it as follows :

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); //R.id.button is the id on your xml
edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); //this is the EditText id
```

*Oh wait, I've read the question again and I forgot something, just add on your xml this:*

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="What's 2x2?" <!-- This is the question-->
android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Then the next step is set an [`onClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) on your `Button` so you can get the event when user clicks on it. You can do it as follows :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
   // Perform action on click 
   //Here you must get the text on your EditText
   String Answer = (String) edittext.getText().toString(); //here you have the text typed by the user
   //You can make an if statement to check if it's correct or not 
   if(Answer=="4"){
        //Create a Toast because it's correct
        Toast.makeText(MainACtivity.this, "Correct!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
       //It's not the correct answer
       Toast.makeText(MainACtivity.this, "FAAAAAAAAIL!",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
 }
});
```

That's just an example of you could do it, if you want to improve it, just do it by yourself.

As `StackOverflow` says

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

You should [Learn Android Basics](https://www.google.es/search?q=Learn+android+basics&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rs3gVZnKIMG-Utq8v9AI) to learn about Android.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hmm if someone downvote an answer or a question the user should know **WHY** so, I'd appreciate that the guy that did it expalin to me **WHY** he did it.

Comment: Please don't encourage bad questions like this by answering them.  They need to learn how to ask good questions here.  ANd a beginner like this needs to learn to do his own work, or at least try (the code he gave is a homework skeleton from his teacher).  This is clearly someone trying to get somebody else to do his homework.  You aren't helping him or the site.

Comment: @GabeSechan Totally agree, but I just gave a skeleton, this won't do what he says, this is just an example... and on the end of question I gave to him an advice... that's learn android and I gave a google link. But I think  tell to me that It's not a good idea answer when the SO want to solve their homeworks it's enought... and it's not necessary downvote, isn't it?...